# In Go, how to unmarshal a string containing an array of a struct

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, unmarshalling

One of the attributes that I'm receiving from an API is a string containing an array of a struct, where the attributes of the struct are escaped.

I would like data (the output object) to be a simple array of MyStruct like this:

> [{"f":"f-val"}]

However, the output that I get is an empty array [].

Can someone please help? I'd be really grateful.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type MyStruct struct {
    F string
}

func main() {
    stringResponse := `"[{\"f\":\"f-val\"}]"`
    var data []MyStruct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(stringResponse)), &data)
    fmt.Print(data)
}
```

Comment: Check the error returned by `json.Unmarshal`. Anyway, your json is malformed.

Comment: [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote): https://play.golang.org/p/pq-krKTyq3t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is proper example:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "strconv"
)

func main() {
   s, e := strconv.Unquote(`"[{\"f\":\"f-val\"}]"`)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   var (
      b = []byte(s)
      m []struct{F string}
   )
   json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
   println(m[0].F == "f-val")
}
```

Comment: You might be right, but that's what I am getting in the API response{\"f\":\"f-val\"}